# What's a good practice to deal with global strings in angular?

Tags: angular

In our angular application we have a few hardcoded strings across the app (things like labels, error messages, validation messages) and would like to organize that mess a bit. I read a few answers on stackoverflow about global strings but I couldn't understand if this is a bad practice or not (for example [here](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) they say it's a bad thing).

To me it feels like a regular problem to have, so what are the good practices to deal with global variables in Angular?

Comment: read this article https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be

Comment: a part of the environment files we have some files like app.const.ts and we export constants. Like this: export const col_type = {}

Comment: Honestly, to each his own preference. But global variables are indeed bad, we can all agree on that. My preferred way is [Injection Tokens](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers) and factories, as you can inject the strings directly as dependencies of your components.

Comment: If the strings change when you change an environment (for instance URLs), you can use the environment files to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

You can externalize all of this in json configuration files, loaded at launch. It allows to reuse them multiple time. Moreover, you can define multiple configurations for multiple environments.
Take a look at this article : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/03/01/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/